# Open multiple browsers in incognito / private mode via Powershell

Tags: powershell, multiple-browsers

I want to open a single URL with IE, CH and FF, using incognito/private mode.

I can open the url with the 3 browsers using this Powershell script:

```
Param(
[string] $url
)


[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe", $url)      
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("firefox.exe",$url )


$IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$IE.navigate2($url)
$IE.visible=$true
```

how can I open the browsers in incognito mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`chrome.exe` takes an `--incognito` command line option:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe","--incognito $url")
```

Similarly, `firefox.exe` takes a `-private-window` command line option:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("firefox.exe","-private-window $url")
```

And as noted by @TToni in the comments, for `iexplore.exe` the equivalent is `-private`:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("iexplore.exe","$url -private")
```

The `InternetExplorer.Application` com object doesn't support InPrivate browsing AFAIK

Comment: And Internet Explorers option is "-private" (use it at the end, after the url).

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to launch Microsoft Edge in "InPrivate" mode in the same method as above, it would be the following syntax:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("msedge.exe", "-InPrivate https://google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the new and working script:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("chrome.exe", "--incognito $url")
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("firefox.exe","-private-window $url" )
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("iexplore.exe","$url -private" )
```

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to it :-)